# Stuck with windows Automatic repair loop after installing eOS alongside Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub, startup

I recently installed Elementary OS alongside my windows 10 PC. After successfully installing eOS I can't boot to Windows 10. I click on the option to boot to the partition that windows 10 is installed on and it just gives me the same problems. I'm stuck with an automatic repair loop and whenever I try to reset my pc or troubleshoot it with the command line I can't seem to fix the issue.

Have any of you run into a problem like this before? I could really use your help. I have a lot of data I really don't want to lose. The important stuff is backed up, but the time and energy to reformat everything and reinstall everything is pretty daunting.

Also, when i tried resetting this PC, it went to 90% and then said it undid all the changes.

Comment: I guess the boot record got corrupted. MBR or GPT?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you change to AHCI. Windows was installed on IDE. I had same problem some times ago, try to revert back to IDE and try to boot Windows. If you fix it you need to reinstall elementary to use IDE... or to do whole new installation of Windows with AHCI enabled on boot... Your choice  ;) Good luck ;)